# How to remove a single class only in Javascript using Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

*(Pure javascript only, please!)*

I want to create a helper function that removes a single `class` from a `div` with several classes. I'm imagining a function as follows:

```
function remove_class(div, klass) {
    div.className = div.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)active(?!\S)/ , '' );
}
```

The class removed here is `active`.  However, how can I remove any class name, ie. one passed as the `klass` variable?

Comment: Why not use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList)? The MDN page even has a [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList#wrapper) for browser compatibility

Comment: Limited compatibility is why. :) And this is not a duplicate - it's a much more specific question.

Comment: It's compatible down to IE8 with the shim. And yes, this question is an **exact** duplicate of the other one. The answers are the same too

Comment: No it isn't, because I didn't understand the other answers. I've looked it over several times, in fact. The answer I got here was easy to understand. So thanks for voting to close this question, on behalf of other to come after me.

Comment: No offense, but I think there is a misunderstanding. If the answers are not easy to understand it is not advisable to duplicate the question. Instead you can ask your question as a comment at the initial question. So Phil is right and you have duplicated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead of a RegExp literal. The constructor takes a string as its first param, so you can build it any way you like.

```
function remove_class(div, klass) {
    div.className = div.className.replace( new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + klass + '(?!\\S)'), '' );
}
```

Notice that no delimiters (the leading and trailing forward slashes) are needed when using the constructor.

Comment: I have never used RegExp constructor. Do you have a working example?

Comment: Sorry, it was coming.

Answer (score 1):

Instead using /regexp/ syntax you can use RegExp:
something like this:

```
function remove_class(div, klass) {
    var regex = new RegExp('\/(?:^|\\s)' + klass + '(?!\\S)\/');
    div.className = div.className.replace( regex , '' );
}
```

Comment: Note, the RegExp delimiters (leading and trailing forward-slash) are only needed for a RegExp literal.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the regexp like so:

```
var re = new RegExp("regex","g");
```

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/494046/1778812

Comment: If this question was a duplicate, you should have flagged it as such

Comment: @Phil rep not high enough to vote-to-close. (Copying answers between questions is still stupid.)

Comment: Is there a single answer in so-called duplicate with the syntax of the accepted answer to this question? `new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + klass + '(?!\\S)'), '' ` No.